# Long press time consider for GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart

**Problem:**

I built minesweeper and 350ms is too much to trigger the longPress event, I need more speed.
I need implement time consider for GestureDetector, i need 200ms for detect long press event.

**How my system build:**

Every button use onTap and LongPress event.

**My test:**

I try to use this package:
[XGestureDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/gesture_x_detector)

But it works bad because in different device not works.

I had seen but the onTap event does not work this way:
[StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67383938/15047923)

*I need a method to solve my problem.*

Comment: create a custom gesture /InkWell for yourself

Comment: @AwaisRehman If it were that simple I would have done it already. Have you idea?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `onTap event does not work this way`. Because with a similar approach, I was able to achieve what you need. You just need to pass correct behavior to it. Please check my answer below and let me know your opinion on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @salihgueler answer,
I found the solution:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late Timer _timer;
  bool isLongPressed = false; 
  
  void _startOperation() {
    _timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
      print('LongPress Event');
      isLongPressed= true; 
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        _startOperation();    
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        _timer.cancel();
        if(!isLongPressed)
        {
          print("Is a onTap event");
        }
        else 
        {
          isLongPressed = false; 
        }
      },
      child: Text(
        'Hello, World!',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing it. I will show you something that I came up with that can help you start out with.

It starts a timer on each tap to the child and cancels it when you take your hand off. It takes advantage of onTapDown and onTapUp from GestureDetector, a widget that you are familiar from Flutter ecosystem.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late Timer _timer;

  void _startOperation() {
    _timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
      print('Do something after delay');
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        _startOperation();    
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        _timer.cancel();
      },
      child: Text(
        'Hello, World!',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good option, but you catch only longPress.

Comment: Well in that case, you can use StopWatch instead and do the operation according to elapsed time. What do you think?

Comment: Please you make easy example @salihgueler

Answer (score 1):

I've sometimes had some issues with `GestureDetector`, so here's an alternate solution that uses a [`Listener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html).

```dart
class CustomHoldListener extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomHoldListener({
    this.holdDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    this.onTap,
    this.onHold,
    super.key,
  });

  final Duration holdDuration;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final VoidCallback? onHold;

  @override
  State<CustomHoldListener> createState() => _CustomHoldListenerState();
}

class _CustomHoldListenerState extends State<CustomHoldListener> {
  Duration? lastPointerDownTime;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (event) {
        lastPointerDownTime = event.timeStamp;
      },
      onPointerUp: (event) {
        if (lastPointerDownTime != null) {
          if (event.timeStamp - lastPointerDownTime! > widget.holdDuration) {
            widget.onHold?.call();
            return;
          }
        }
        
        widget.onTap?.call();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good alternatives!