# fluttersIn gesture detector on long press it should stop same page and when release it should move to next page ? How to achieve this in flutter

Tags: flutter

In gesture detector on long press it should stop same page and when release it should move to next page ? How to achieve this in flutter.

am expecting some logic.

Comment: Have you try yet ? approach that i could think of right now is detect press duration::> https://stackoverflow.com/a/67740891/19533443

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use `GestureDetector`. And use the property of `onLongPressEnd`

```
GestureDetector(
    onLongPressEnd: (_) {
    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
     );
   },
 ),
```

Comment: & if if it shows any error then do Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) =>...... );